# ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8) in altcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin

I am trying to create altcoin(Abccoin) from bitcoin and change parameters in chainparams.cpp and also generated the genesis block hash and hashMerkleRoot but when I start the daemon with 
**`abccoind -daemon`**

I get the error in debug.log :

```
ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)
```

Using -reindex also doesn't solve the problem, then I got another error :

```
ERROR: AcceptBlock: high-hash, proof of work failed (code 16)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I used the `CreateGenesisBlock` function.

Comment: I met same problem. have you solved? Any updates? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your genesis block has an invalid Proof of Work.

Comment: so that means I have to again generate hash with different valid genesis block

Comment: How to check if the PoW of the genesis block is valid?

Comment: You actually have to mine the genesis block (it's very easy to do) and check its proof of work when it is being created. You can do that with a while loop to increment the nonce and the `CheckProofOfWork()` function.

Comment: @AndrewChow Hi. So again me.. How exactly do that in chainparams.cpp? If I write CheckProofOfWork() in chainparams.cpp (of course #include "pow.h"), error says........... undefined reference to "CheckProofOfWork(..."

Comment: ok, so I solved link problem, revised makefile.am, and wrote like while(!CheckProofOfWork(genesis.GetHash(), genesis.nBits,,,,, )){ ++genesis.nNonce; }, but still got CBlockDiskPos error with ./xxxcoind run, or AcceptBlock: high-hash, proof of work failed (code 16), Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer error with ./xxxcoind -reindex